# git clone fails on windows, local network

Tags: windows, git, nas

After I've wasted about two hours trying to clone a git repository on my fresh Windows 10 installation I felt like I had to share my solution with the outer world.

Setting is this: I created a bare repository on my NAS (didn't name it *.git since I didn't know that convention existed). After a few pushes from my Windows 8.1 (and other) I upgraded to Windows 10. Sadly that killed my project located at the *desktop* (can't find it in *Windows.old*). "No big deal", I thought, "got my stuff on the NAS, right". So I tried (having git for windows):

```
git clone ssh://myuser@nasip/path/to/project
```

which gave me `...does not appear to be a git repository` ... mhmmm. Okay maybe ssh ain't working, let's check something else:

```
git clone git://nasip/path/to/project
```

Same thing there. Okay, lets try `http:://` ... nothing. `https://`? Certificate error. Well, at least.

Okay then, let's try to drop the IP (could be some firewall stuff, right?). Let's use `\\nas\path\to\project` instead.

```
git clone git://\\nas\path\to\project
git clone git://\\\\nas\\path\\to\\project
git clone "git://\\nas\path\to\project"
git clone git://nas/path/to/project
```

Nope, nope, nope, nope. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What finally worked was this:

```
git clone \file:////nas/path/to/project
```